# With Watin, how do I wait until an element gets a certain CSS class?

Tags: c#, css, watin

I want to use Watin's `WaitUntil` method to wait until an element gets a certain CSS class (JavaScript adds the class dynamically). How do I do this?

```
var element = browser.Div("my-div");
element.WaitUntil(...);  // What to do here??
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try one of these:

```
element.WaitUntil(Find.ByClass("your_class_name"));
element.WaitUntil(d => d.ClassName == "your_class_name");
```

Keep in mind, that element with `class="your_class_name other_class_name"` will probably (I'm not 100% sure) not be found.

Comment: The second form is basically what I needed, thanks! Not sure how I missed trying it myself, as I was trying a lambda in some way.